# Adding Sorting on Birt Table Column which is not part of Groups breaks Grouping

Tags: java, birt

Hi I Have a Birt Table in which I have set Sort By Group : False.
I have put my own sorting for the table but grouping is getting break. I have two layers of grouping for my Table.

[image]

After Sorting grouping is getting break as the Sorting column is not part of grouped Column. Please see the below image how grouped data is coming :
[image]

I want to create a column binding which has the value of First Group + Second Group then in my sorting Script I will append my third column value after. But while creating column binding I am not able to get the groups Data. Please suggest how to achieve this ?

Comment: In Column Binding script I want to access the DataSet values per row that I am considering for Grouping. Please let me know how get that ?

Comment: May be you want to expand why "Sort By Groups" property is turned off, this could help us to understand what you need to achieve. Usually from the expression builder of a table column binding we are able to select any dataset field: you should provide more infomations about what you see  through this expression builder

Comment: Thanks @Dominique. In my Birt Tarble I have defined Grouping as well as some sorting script under Sorting tab. Is there any property by which I can say First Sort then Group or First Group Then Sort.
I want to understand the How Birt do Grouping and Sorting at the same time.

Comment: BIRT groups by the sort key, then the groups are sorted by that key. You can also specify how items are sorted within the groups. Which makes total sense. A big pile of information is grouped so you get individual stacks that have something (the key) in common. You can decide how to sort the stacks (the groups) and how you sort the items in each stack.
So from you example, I don't understand what is wrong with the second picture. It is exactly what I would expect. Please add a table with raw data and one with how you want the end result to be.